# How to start a new android project so that i can still upload the newly made app on the old dev account

Tags: android, google-play

I have changed my idea but i still want to keep the same app on the playstore ( downloads etc. ) but want to start from scratch.

Comment: 1) use same keystore to sign it 2) use same package name 3) increment version code 4) good to go

Comment: Yeah its the same question. Sorry, couldn't find that question among the suggested ones.

Comment: No worries. If you could confirm the duplicate by clicking the banner on top of your question that would be great

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yup. Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Just keep the ApplicationID(package name).
2. Change Version Code(increment) and version Name(optional).
3. Keep same signing certificate used previously for building APK.
4. Then just upload new APK for that application/game.

Comment: Hey. Looks a lot like my comment.

Comment: @TimCastelijns didn't see that.. well answer is same so it must be similar.

Comment: It's fine. It's a duplicate anyway. Would you mind flagging it?

Comment: What if i have "sign in with google" will the use of the new project change the sha5 key for dev and production?

Comment: if you keep the above mentioned things same...you don't need to worry about other things.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all those who contributed! :)